# Не получается вывести dd

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Подскажите пожалуйста почему у меня не выводится то что я хочу?

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
x dd ? 
y dd 6 
n dd ? 
m dd 30 
 .code 

 start: 
   invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 
push ebx 
mov ebx, n 
inc n 
.while m != ebx 
pop ebx 
mov eax, x 
add eax, y 
mov x, eax 
mov eax, x 
print str$ (eax) 
push ebx 
mov ebx, n 
inc n 
.endw 
 Main endp 

 end start
```

Вкратце словами

```
Есть цикл с условием от n=0 до m=30, так вот внутри него у меня просто происходит сложение двух чисел(x=x+y) и последующий вывод числа x.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно убрать `__UNICODE__ equ 1`, и вывод станет таким:

```
6121824303642485460667278849096102108114120126132138144150156162168174180
```

Видимо, нужно еще добавить перевод строки после каждого числа.

Также, программа будет "падать" из-за того, что у вас в процедуре `Main` нет инструкции возврата управления `ret`. Кроме того, перед `ret` нужно будет добавить восстановление регистра `ebx` из стека (`pop ebx`).