# Не правильно выводится текст в макросе Inkey

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Почему неправильно выводится текст? Выводятся какие-то квадратики :((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 .486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 

 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
saida2 db "wtfff",0

 .code 

 start: 
   invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 
 inkey offset saida2
 Main endp
```

Answer (score 1):

Аналогично ответу в [данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504298/1365) - нужно убрать `__UNICODE__ equ 1`.

В коде есть и другие проблемы: например, нет инструкции `end` в конце, из-за чего программа не будет компилироваться, также в конце процедуры `Main` нет `ret`, из-за чего программа будет "падать".